# Close all applications in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos

Is there any hotkey, AppleScript or separate application for that?
I don't really like kill 20 applications manually every time I make reboot.

Comment: Do you have to kill the applications before or after reboot?

Answer (score 1):

The Finder should safely quit any open apps whenever you logout or reboot. If there is a document with unsaved changes It will prompt you to save or discard the changes before quitting. The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>.

If you do not want all the apps restarting when you log back in, uncheck the "Reopen windows when logging back in" checkbox in the logout dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You can often just hold ⌘Q, or uncheck "Reopen windows when logging back in" in the ⇧⌘Q dialog. Anyway, here is a shell script that quits applications shown in the Dock in parallel:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for a in $(osascript -e 'set text item delimiters to linefeed
tell app "System Events" to name of processes where background only is false
result as text'); do osascript -e 'on run {x}
quit app x
end' -- "$a" &
done
```

You can [assign it a shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) with an application like Alfred or FastScripts.